# sql , image converting type to varbinary

Tags: sql, image

guys how to convert pic ?

i have 'jpg' picture on my computer desktop  " i want the SQL 'varbinary(MAX)'  value of it" 
how to do it ?

Note that : the image is on my desktop and i cant attache  it on SQL database

Answer (score 0):

```
public byte[] ImageLoader(string ImageAddress)
    {
        StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(ImageAddress);
        return Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(SR.ReadToEnd());
    }
```

Comment: You can use CLR for import C# functions into sql
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28129/Creating-a-CLR-Persian-Date-Convertor-Function-for